# Android root detection using build tags?

Tags: android, root

The following method is one of the ways we can programatically detect if an android device is rooted:

```
public boolean checkRootMethod1(){
    String buildTags = android.os.Build.TAGS;

    if (buildTags != null && buildTags.contains("test-keys")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Can someone explain what this is actually doing? What is the "test-keys" build tag, and what does it have to do with root? I couldn't find any relevant information from google.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Release-Keys and Test-Keys has to do with how the kernel is signed when it is compiled. Release-Keys means it was signed with an official Key from an official developer. Test-Keys means it was signed with a custom key generated by a third-party developer. From a security standpoint Release-Keys generally means the kernel is more secure, which is not always the case.

Comment: It says test-keys when the build is signed with the public AOSP test keys, not when a custom key is used. It will say release-keys when the build is signed using proper keys, third party or not.

Answer (score 2):

```
String buildTags = android.os.Build.TAGS;
```

This code is for getting `build.prop` located in `/system/build.prop`. As you can see you are getting `android.os.Build.TAGS` that means you are getting `ro.build.tags` value inside `build.prop`. here is the [code of build.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/Build.java)

For your second question I can not make sure it will work because my `ro.build.tags` string is `release-keys` in my rooted device.

Comment: Do you know what the keys mean exactly?

Comment: Better question - What is the difference between `release-keys` and `test-keys`?