# Why do rooted phone have test-keys on build tag?

Tags: android

I've been seeing methods for detectiing a rooted android device. One of them is checking for "test-keys" on android.os.Build.TAGS. Is test-keys a universal tag to describe a rooted android device?

Comment: A clever enough hacker could make that disappear (since he got root access)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, how? don't we need to install a new build/ install a customized ROM?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android root detection using build tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808705/android-root-detection-using-build-tags)

Comment: @kaz You could use a hooking framework like Xposed to spoof the value returned from Build.Tags or change the contents of the underlying store/file -> /system/build.prop. Later is only an assumption, the first approach has been tested by myself.